# Separator between statements in awk

Tags: awk, gawk

From Gawk's manual:

> When awk statements within one rule are short, you might want to put
>   more than one of them on a line. This is accomplished by separating
>   the statements with a semicolon (‘;’). This also applies to the rules
>   themselves. Thus, the program shown at the start of this section could
>   also be written this way:
>
> ```
> /12/ { print $0 } ; /21/ { print $0 }
> ```
>
> NOTE: The requirement that states that rules on the same line must be
>   sepa rated with a semicolon was not in the original awk language; it
>   was added for consistency with the treatment of statements within an
>   action.

But I have seen from https://stackoverflow.com/q/20262869/156458

```
awk '$2=="no"{$3="N/A"}1' file
```

Aren't `$2=="no"{$3="N/A"}` and `1` two statements? why are they not separated by anything?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Very good question! I think the key is this: *"Thus, the program shown at the start of this section **could also be written** this way:"*

Is not mandatory to be written in this way. It is a kind of alternative way. This means (and has been proved in action) that below statements are  both correct :

```
$ awk '/12/ { print $0 } /21/ { print $0 }' file
$ awk '/12/ { print $0 } ; /21/ { print $0 }' file
```

I think this semicolon usage is to cover really short - idiomatic code , for example cases that we omit the action part and we want to apply multiple rules on the same line:

```
$ awk '/12//21/' file
awk: cmd. line:2: /12//21/
awk: cmd. line:2:         ^ unexpected newline or end of string
```

In this case using a semicolon is mandatory to separate rules (=conditions):

```
$ awk '/12/;/21/' file
```

Since the `{action}` part is ommited in both rules/both conditions, the default action will be performed for every rule = `{print $0}`

Comment: I believe that (for action-pattern lists): The semicolon **after** an action closing brace **is** optional.

Comment: good answer but i'm not sure that `'/12/;/21/'` is all that common as awk idiom.  IMO & IME it's more common to write something like that as `'/12|21/'` - more efficient too, only one regexp match rather than two or more.

Comment: @cas The use of `/12/;/21/` is a simpliied example to demonstrate why semicolon is necessary to separate rules / conditions. For simple tasks , you are right, we can use just one regex with `or`. Someone can extend this "conditions only" syntax to more complicated conditions , i.e `awk ' $1==10;$2+$NF<100' file`. But since in all conditions the action is the same = `{print $0}` , theoritically we can use OR everywhere : `awk '$1==10 || $2+$NF<10' file`

Comment: yes, i know. that was kind of my point.  it doesn't make sense to have multiple statements with different patterns and the SAME action.  it makes a lot more sense to have a single pattern with a more complex regex and/or multiple OR-ed conditionals:  `a || b || c || d || e {action}` rather than `a {action}; b {same action}; c {same action again} ...`.  easier to change a single common action for all those patterns too.  in other words, while this is something you **can** do, it's also something you almost never want to.  I thought that was worth adding to your answer.

Answer (score 6):

In gawk, this two quote [from the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Action-Overview) describe the issue:

> An action consists of one or more awk statements, enclosed in braces (‘{…}’). Each statement specifies one thing to do. The statements are separated by newlines or semicolons.

A semicolon is a "**separator**" but not a "**terminator**".
The only valid terminator of an action is a closing brace (`}`).

Therefore, what follows an action closing brace (`}`) must be some other *pattern{action}*

In the "man **mawk**" there is some other description that may help clarify what awk should do:

> Statements  are  terminated  by  newlines, semi-colons or both.  Groups of statements such as actions or loop bodies are blocked via { ... } as in C.  The last statement in a block  doesn't  need  a  terminator.

The "man **nawk**" explains it like this:

> The pattern comes first, and then the action. Action statements are enclosed in { and }.

And, if you want to dwell into the detail, [read the POSIX description](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html):

```
action           : '{' newline_opt                             '}'
                 | '{' newline_opt terminated_statement_list   '}'
                 | '{' newline_opt unterminated_statement_list '}'
                 ;
```

And search for what is an "unterminated" statement list.

Or, simpler, search for [Action](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_09) to read:

> Any single statement can be replaced by a statement list enclosed in curly braces. The application shall ensure that statements in a statement list are separated by <newline> or <semicolon> characters.

Again: `are separated by <newline> or <semicolon> characters`

Answer (score 3):

The semicolon between conditional blocks appears to be optional; only the semicolons between statements *within* blocks appear to be mandatory:

```
$ echo -e "foo\nbar" | gawk '/foo/ { print "foo found" } /bar/ {print "bar found"}'
foo found
bar found
$ echo -e "foo\nbar" | gawk '/foo/ { print "foo found" }; /bar/ {print "bar found"}'
foo found
bar found
$ echo -e "foo\nbar" | gawk '/foo/ { print "foo found"; print "whee" }'
foo found
whee
$ echo -e "foo\nbar" | gawk '/foo/ { print "foo found" print "whee" }'
gawk: cmd. line:1: /foo/ { print "foo found" print "whee" }
gawk: cmd. line:1:                           ^ syntax error
```

However, when the actual code block between two conditionals is omitted in favor of the default (i. e. `{print}`), the semicolon becomes necessary:

```
$ echo -e "foo\nbar" | gawk '/foo/ /bar/'
gawk: cmd. line:2: /foo/ /bar/
gawk: cmd. line:2:            ^ unexpected newline or end of string
$ echo -e "foo\nbar" | gawk '/foo/; /bar/'
foo
bar
```

Comment: Great minds something something.

Comment: I believe that:  The semicolon **after** a closing brace **is** optional.